# ng-repeat + ng-animate + css3 transition

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, delay, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I have a huge delay in ng-repeat on re-initialization of collection (elements are disappearing from DOM with delay) when I use ng-animation and css3 transition.

I have ng-repeat that create card directive on each iteration:

```
ng-repeat="card in cards track by $index" card
```

there is a some transition on root node of card directive:

```
.card {
        transition: transform 0.2s linear;
        transform: translateX(0);
}
```

the problem is appearing when cards collection is re-initialized `$scope.cards = []`

Do you have any idea how to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should use transition on event not in the normal state of the element. I think the linear transition will happen if after .card is loaded you add second class .effect and put the transform in it.